# stored procedure can't figure out how to insert results into existing table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have seen many posts on this but unfortunately I have not been able to use them to my benefit.  Like many other I would like to take the results of a stored procedure and as part of the procedure, every time it is run have the results go into an already existing table.  I cannot figure out how to do this and also how to match the columns up.

For example, the existing table has 4 columns.  2 of those columns are string and the stored procedure needs to hard code those values (a fixed name and definition for each procedure).  I have 4 stored procedures and each one needs to have the 'name' and 'description' defined in it.  This accounts for 2 of the 4 columns in the existing 'output' table.  The remaining two columns, one needs to show the datetime the procedure was run, and the other whether the check passed or failed.

my procedure works fine, up to outputting results.

the existing output table, lets call it 'dbo.procedure_results'.  it has 4 columns (checkname, description, asofdate, and pass)

there are 4 procedures, let's call them dbo.p1, dbo. p2....

each procedure when run currently outputs a file date and a total allocated storage integer (in TB).  I need to define 'checkname' and 'description' for each procedure.  'asofdate' can be the datetime the procuedure was run  Pass is an if statement, if the difference between returned values 1 and 3 are X, then Y, else z.

**My current procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_DQ_SAN_Hosts_200TB_TotalCapacity]

AS
BEGIN

SELECT top 3 (CONVERT(date, day)) as Ref_Date, sum(TotalAllocated_TB)

  FROM [STORAGE_DW].[dbo].[SMART_Host_Dash]
  where TotalAllocated_TB >50
  GROUP BY cast(Day as date)
  order by CONVERT(date, day) desc

  insert into dbo.dq_check_summary 
  exec dbo.sp_dq_san_hosts_200tb_totalcapacity 

  END
```

procedure currently outputs:

```
Ref_Date     Allocated_TB
2017-05-29   898.868404388428
2017-04-24   1056.01000595093
2017-03-27   779.119682312012
```

Comment: You didn't share your error, so guessing here.  If the table has four columns, but stored proc has only two column output, then it should fail. Try specifying the two column names in the INSERT statement.  ie `insert into dbo.dq_check_summary (col1, col2) exec dbo.sp_dq_san_hosts_200tb_totalcapacity`

Comment: Do you want it to insert AND return the results?  Or just insert?  As it currently is, it would appear to create an infinite recursion that would never terminate

Comment: In this sp do you need to select the results and then insert it into a table?

Comment: oh sorry.  well there are many different errors.  some are invalid column name, most of the time i just cant get the procedure to run when i try to insert results into.  the number of columns is 4 vs 2 and the names do not match

Comment: also to your AND question.  No, i don't need to return the result, just use the result of the initial procedure to then do an if statement.  the result of the if statement would be returned in the form of a 'pass' or 'fail'

Comment: Something is very wrong here. The recursion aspect is a big red flag. The other issue is you state you have error messages. The challenge is we can't see your screen, have no idea what your table structures are like...we can't help with vague explanations like "here are many different errors". Give us the details and we can help. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: Slight detour but you should consider a better prefix to your procedure names, or even better no prefix at all. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Another slight detour. If you create your procedure with a name that contains all capital letters, then spell it the **SAME WAY** when you execute it. Save yourself (or someone else more likely) the pain of having to discover your assumption about case-insensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is suspicious - much like the idea that the condition "TotalAllocated_TB > 50" corresponds to the name you gave to your procedure. But you simply change the select statement to include the literals you want. E.g.,

```
select top 3 'what you want for checkname' as 'check name', 
'what you want for description' as 'description', 
cast([day] as date) as refdate, 
...
order by refdate;
```

Note that you can use an alias in the order by clause. Don't need to repeat the expression. Notice that you are summing and you filter the selected rows. Are you certain this logic is correct? The filter occurs logically before the summing? Be careful you understand that and that your sample data is sufficient to validate your logic. And **do not** write an insert statement that does not specify the columns to be inserted. Ever!

```
insert into dbo.dq_check_summary (col1, col2, col3, col4)
execute dbo.blah;
```

Since your procedure is relatively trivial, you might consider using table-valued functions rather than a procedure. That would require a different approach but might be easier (in the long run) to use generally. In fact, you could create a view to do this - which might be a better choice for someone without much tsql experience. A view can generate the resultset you desire - you then decide if you want to insert the results into table when you query the view.